# Spark HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN can't be found in cache

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, hdp

```
I am running simplest Driver alone long running job to reproduce this error
Hadoop Version        2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292 
Spark-core version    2_11.2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292
```

---

```
Code:
FileSystem fs = tmpPath.getFileSystem(sc.hadoopConfiguration())
log.info("Path {} is ",path,fs.exists(tmpPath);
```

> Behaviour: My job runs without any problem for ~17-18 hours, After that new keys are released as a part of `HadoopFSDelagationTokenProvider` and job continued to run with newly issued delegated tokens, But within next 1hour of delegation token renew, job fails with error token can't be found in cache. I have gone ahead and generated my own dfs.adddelegationtoken programatically for involved namenodes, and i see same behaviour.
>
> Question:
>
> 1. What are the chances that delegation token gets removed from server and what properties controls this?.
> 2. What server side logs shows this token is about get removed or removed from cache.

```
Path /test/abc.parquet is true
Path /test/abc.parquet is true
INFO Successfully logged into KDC
INFO getting token for DFS[DFSClient][clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_2324234_29,ugi=qa_user@ABC.com(auth:KERBEROS)](org.apache.spark.deploy.security.HadoopFSDelagationTokenProvider)
INFO Created HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 31615466 for qa_user on ha:hdfs:hacluster
INFO getting token for DFS[DFSClient][clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_2324234_29,ugi=qa_user@ABC.com(auth:KERBEROS)](org.apache.spark.deploy.security.HadoopFSDelagationTokenProvider)
INFO Created HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 31615467 for qa_user on ha:hdfs:hacluster
INFO writing out delegation tokens to hdfs://abc/user/qa/.sparkstaging/application_121212.....tmp
INFO delegation tokens written out successfully, renaming file to hdfs://.....
INFO delegation token file rename complete(org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.security.AMCredentialRenewer)
Scheduling login from keytab in 64799125 millis
Path /test/abc.parquet is true
Path /test/abc.parquet is true

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken): token (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 31615466 for qa_user) can't be found in cache
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1554)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1498)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1398)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.getListing(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:620)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

> ```
> FYI submitted in yarn-cluster-mode with:
> --keytab /path/to/the/headless-keytab,
> --principal principalNameAsPerTheKeytab 
> --conf spark.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=true
> Note that Token renewer is issuing new keys and new keys are working too, But it;s somehow gets revoked from server, AM logs doesn't have any clue on the same.
> ```

Comment: There are many other questions but none have proper followups, Let me know if you need any details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Answering my own question:
>
> There are couple of very important points to take from here.
>
> 1. Delegation token is a single copy stored in UserGroupInformation.getCredentials.getAllTokens(), This can get
>    updated by any other thread running in the save JVM. My problem was
>    fixed by setting
>    `mapreduce.job.complete.cancel.delegation.tokens=false` for all other
>    jobs running in the same contexts, especially the ones run MAPREDUCE
>    contexts.
> 2. HadoopFSDelagationTokenProvider should renew keys for every `(fraction*renewal time)` i.e. default `0.75*24 hrs` if you have submitted
>    job with --keytab and --principal
> 3. Make sure you set `fs.disable.cache` for hdfs filesystem i.e. every time you get new filesystem object, it's costly operation but you get fresh
>    fsObject with new keys for sure instead of getting it from
>    `CACHE.get(fsname)`.
>
> In case if none work you can create your own delegation tokens by
> calling with new Credentials()
> https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#addDelegationTokens(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials)
> but this method must be called with `kerberosUGI.doAS({});`